4 Most Important Questions For Smart Contracts Developers
Hello Smart Contracts Developers

Which Blockchain like Etherscan, Bscscan, Polygonscan, Tronscan.... etc that automatically approve new token logo and token value application?

Which stable coin listing websites like coinmarketcap, coingecko..... etc automatically list new tokens in their websites after a new token is submitted for listing in their website?

Can token logo in GitHub be imported into a new token smart contract for the new token to display token logo after it's deployment on mainnet?

Can token value | token USD price in coinmarketcap be imported into a new token smart contract for the new token to display token value  | token USD price after it's deployment to mainnet?



The pages you mention in 1. are block explorers. Some are run by Etherscan others are run by a different entity. For the sites in 2. each site has its own policy. You have to ask each of them individually. Prices are usually gathered from different sources, exchanges, markets, etc.
